# The Cantor set is uncountable even though it is a closed set with outer meaure $0.$ ("Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler. )

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, cantor-set

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

The author wrote the following sentence.

> Sentence 1:
> Now we can use the Cantor function to show that the Cantor set is uncountable even though it is a closed set with outer meaure $0.$

Why did the author write "***closed***" in the above sentence?

The following sentence is also true.
But the author didn't write the following sentence.

> Sentence 2:
> Now we can use the Cantor function to show that the Cantor set is uncountable even though it is a set with outer meaure $0.$

Would you be less surprised if the author wrote Sentence 2 instead of Sentence 1?

Comment: Obviously, the first one is stronger.

Comment: It is difficult to ensure what the author really thought to write a specific sentence.  I would guess he has chosen such wording maybe because trivial examples  of closed sets with measure 0 are typically finite or at most countable. For instance: $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you very much for your comment.